Move elements separately in Geometry Nodes?
I have created 5 different curves. These are "elements" created within Geometry Nodes. (I would use Separate Children when using a collection). I would like to achieve the same effect and place the curves on the points on the curve. When I use Instance on Points, the entire group is copied to those points. Could someone give me some guidance on how to move individual curves separately? (I have tried Accumulate.) Any help would be appreciated.
Here are my curves:

This is the result where the whole group is copied, instead of each curve separately on each point.


To achieve your goal, you need your curves in the form of referenceable objects.
For example, you can use the Geometry to Instance node instead of the Join Geometry node.
This combines the objects created at the input into individual objects, which can then be instantiated directly at your points.
Note, however, that the checkbox Pick Instance is activated, as this is the only way to select the objects one after the other when instantiating them:

Alternatively, in version 4.1 you can also separate the geometry into objects using Split to Instances and then instantiate them:

Of course, you can also use individual objects from a collection in the same way. In this case, however, you simply use the Collection Info node as input (and don't forget to activate Separate Children):


Awesome response!!!! I am excited because I struggled with it for hours. I'll try it! Thank you very much!

@JSM_Parametr If your question has been answered satisfactorily, please mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer" so that the question appears as solved. Thank you very much!
